# How does Tesla's autopilot generate 3d reconstruction of road?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, autonomous-vehicles

Tesla uses stereo vision and in many applications it works OK but ground reconstruction is uniquely difficult since there aren't features to match.

I'm wondering how 3d reconstruction works here? Does the autopilot assume the ground plane is flat or is something else going on to infer road curvature?

Comment: Tesla's autopilot likely uses a combination of sensor data and mapping data to generate a 3D reconstruction of the road. The exact details of how this is done are likely proprietary information. However, it is likely that the autopilot uses the data to generate a 3D model of the road that it can then use to navigate.